# How to display a remote Linux manual (through ftp/http/https)?

Tags: man

There are manuals available online (e.g [linux.die.com](https://linux.die.net/man/) or [man.he.net](http://man.he.net/)).

1. **How can I read a manual from terminal  that is on a remote ftp/http/https page? (like e.g `man <cmd_name>`)**
2. **How can I search for manuals that are on a remote http/https page? ( like `man -k <keyword>`)**

Answer (score 2):

Just answering your questions...

> 1. How can I read a manual that is on a remote ftp/http/https page?

Best suitable for that job is a webbrowser like Firefox or the one you prefer.

> 2. How can I search for manuals that are on a remote http/https page?

As far as I can tell, the sites you mentioned in your question do provide a search function. Use that one or a search engine you prefer.

Comment: I was obviously looking for a terminal interface display (1) and terminal search, like `man -k`

Comment: There are a couple of terminal web-browsers like `links` or `lynx`.

Comment: I need the `man` interface and its `less`  functions (e.g marks) . I'd better download them all and run a monthly cron job to check for new uploaded manuals.